# create matrix in which for every element of matrix B found closest element of matrix A

Tags: matlab, matrix

So I can't find simple way of solving following problem:
I've got two matrices with same amount of rows:

```
A = [547   184   929   306;
     296   368   776   509;
     745   626   487   511;
     189   780   436   818;
     687    81   447   795]
B = [644   939   208   195   311   980;
     379   876   301   226   923   439;
     812   550   471   171   430   111;
     533   622   230   228   185   258;
     351   587   844   436   905   409]
```

How can I create matrix C (size(C)=size(B)) in which for every element of matrix B found closest element of matrix A from corresponding row.
In current case:

```
C =

   547   929   184   184   306   929
   368   776   296   296   776   509
   745   511   487   487   487   487
   436   780   189   189   189   189
   447   687   795   447   795   447
```

For the moment I've only thought of this:

```
temp = bsxfun(@eq,abs(bsxfun(@minus,repmat(A,1,1,size(B,2)),permute(B,[1,3,2]))),min(abs(bsxfun(@minus,repmat(A,1,1,size(B,2)),permute(B,[1,3,2]))),[],2));

C = permute(sum(temp.*repmat(A,1,1,size(B,2)),2),[1,3,2]);
```

So is there any easy and more understandable way to solve this task?

Comment: Are there any other problems with the solution you have got apart from readability?

Comment: I think your implementation is doing just what you want, and if you have problems with readability you could split the function by defining help-variables. Otherwise if you are really unhappy with your solution check: [mathworks documentation: dsearchn](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/dsearchn.html). This is a link to `dsearchn()` which could do the trick. But i think ti searches the whole matrix A and not only one row

Comment: Nope, everything works just fine, only huge amount of same function bothers me. Even time of calcualtion is good.

Comment: Note that `repmat`s within your `bsxfun`s could be removed. In fact, the very purpose of `bsxfun` is to avoid having to use `repmat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three `bsxfun` can be reduced to one by using the second output of `min`, which gives the position of the minimum (first line of my code). Those positions are then converted to a linear index, which is applied to `A` (second line):

```
[~, jj] = min(abs(bsxfun(@minus, permute(A, [1 3 2]), B)), [], 3);
C = A(sub2ind(size(B), ndgrid(1:size(B,1),1:size(B,2)), jj));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using nearest neighbour interpolation:

```
for row = 1:size(A,1)
  I = interp1(A(row,:), 1:size(A,2), B(row,:), 'nearest','extrap');
  C(row,:)=A(row,I);
end
```